# how to specify python version in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I need to run python 3.5 but my Jupyter notebook runs 3.6 instead.
It seems I can only specify either python 3 or python 2.

How do I specify it to run 3.5, not 3.6?

Some context: I'm trying to solve this error.

```
/home/duhduh/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.5 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.6
  return f(*args, **kwds)
```

Comment: You **need to pre-activate** the Anaconda ( ENVIRONMENT ), so as to direct into py3.5 pre-configured ecosystem. There is no way to instruct a 3.6 python interpreter already running to become 3.5 instead. Read **`conda`** environment-manager manual for setup + configuration details

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the [TensorFlow installation instructions](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/) for your OS and use [Conda](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html) to create a separate environment for TensorFlow with Python 3.5.

After downloading Conda you just need to run the following command in the terminal to create the environment. Here is the command for Ubuntu/OSX (Windows is similar).

```
$ conda create -n tensorflow pip python=3.5
```

The remainder of the TensorFlow installation instructions are OS specific. Don't forget to activate the newly created environment prior to use. The following command should work for Ubuntu/OSX (Windows command is similar).

```
$ source activate tensorflow
```